# How to get the device address with ASK SDK v2 for Node.js

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build a skill which needs to get access to the device address by using [ASK SDK v2 for Node.js](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs). However, I found the documentation for this v2 extremely limited and even with the sample they provide on Github, it just doesn't work.

So far I understood the following:

1. In your Alexa skill's permissions you need to enable "Full Address" or "Country/Region & Postal Code Only" depending on your use case.
2. Before making the API Call to the device, you need to get the deviceId, accessToken and apiEndpoint. I've done that with the following:

   ```
   const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
     return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
     const speechText = 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello!';
     const accessToken = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.apiAccessToken;
     const deviceId = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.deviceId;
     const apiEndpoint = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.apiEndpoint;

     console.log('accessToken: ' + accessToken + '; deviceId: ' + deviceId + '; apiEndpoint: ' + apiEndpoint);

   return handlerInput.responseBuilder
     .speak(speechText)
     .reprompt(speechText)
     .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
     .getResponse();
    },
   };
   ```
3. In the call, we need to add the Authorization Bearer in the header.

All of this is great but how do we make the call?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't you need to do something like this to get the address? https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api/blob/d056288c52b17479e3fab5a315bf1a3dbd699fc2/lambda/custom/index.js#L52

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call the Alexa address endpoint like so:

```
Host: api.amazonalexa.com
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer MQEWY...6fnLok 
GET https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/{deviceId}/settings/address
```

More details about the address API can be found [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html) With the Node Alexa SDK v2 it might be easier to call the getFullAddress(deviceId) method on the deviceAddressServiceClient as mentioned by Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

Almost two years later, and I agree that documentation is limited. After some research and trial and error I was finally able to get [Amazon's example](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js) to work. I am using ask-sdk@2.8.0.

Typically, your `handlerInput` will come with a `serviceClientFactory` object. This object has a factory function that returns a DeviceAddressServiceClient, and you don't have to worry about setting up the accessToken or apiEndpoint. Just pass your deviceId and you're good to go. Here is a condensed example for a call to get the user's full address:

```
const Alexa = require("ask-sdk");
const address = await handlerInput
    .serviceClientFactory
    .getDeviceAddressServiceClient()
    .getFullAddress(Alexa.getDeviceId(handlerInput.requestEnvelope));
```

Note that getFullAddress returns a Promise. If the user has not authorized the Full Address permission, this function will throw an error where `error.name === "ServiceError"` and `error.statusCode === 403`. You'll want to look for this in a catch clause/function, and return a response that includes `.withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(["read::alexa:device:all:address"])`.

If `handlerInput.serviceClientFactory` is undefined, check the code where you are exporting your skill handler. Are you using `SkillBuilders.custom()` or `SkillBuilders.standard()`? The standard skill builder already includes the default ApiClient, so you should not have an undefined serviceClientFactory with that one. But with the custom option, you do need to specify an ApiClient. You can still use the default client, or provide your own. At the bottom of [Amazon's example](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js), they use the custom builder with the default ApiClient, like this:

```
const Alexa = require("ask-sdk");
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(<your request handlers>)
    .addErrorHandlers(<your error handlers>)
    .withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())
    .lambda();
```

Comments on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/356) helped me find the difference between standard and custom skill builder.